# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
var results = ["img", "some_class"];

for ( var i = 0; i <= results.length; i++ ){

        if (results[i] === "input"){
            elements = [];

        } else if (results[i].indexOf("class") > -1 ){

            className = results[i];
            b = document.getElementsByClassName;

            for ( var i = 0; i < b.length; i++ ){
                elements.push(b[i]);
            }

        } else if (results[i].indexOf("id") > -1 ){

            id = results[i];
            searchId = document.getElementById(id);
            elements.push(searchId);
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to check whether any of the elements in the `results` array contain the strings "class" or "id" but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

You can see that the `results` array does indeed contain "class" inside the second element but my code isn't playing ball.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You can't use `i <= results.length` in your for loop because array's are 0 indexed. When `i` is `==` to `results.length` you're out of bounds!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `<=` at the `for` statement with only a `<`.

In your particular case, `results.length` is 3, so at the last iteration you're trying to access `results[3]`, which is `undefined` and causes the error you get.